# Issue with Hibernate 3 and Null values in DB

Tags: hibernate, null

I'm getting a weird issue with Hibernate 3, with a table that has null values. When I try to select rows from the DB I get the following exception:

> Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter.

The most common fix for this seems to be to change the primitive values to objects, the thing is they are already Objects. Here is my code:

```
package model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
private long pk;
private Date instant;
private String server;
private String ucid;
private String routingVdn;
private String originalCli;
private String originalDnis;
private String terminatingStation;
private String terminatingAgent;
private Date phase1Instant;
private Integer phase1InternalResultCode;
private Integer phase1ExternalResultCode;
private String phase1Message;
private Date phase2Instant;
private Integer phase2InternalResultCode;
private Integer phase2ExternalResultCode;
private String phase2Message;

@Id
@Column( name = "PK")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public long getPk() {
    return pk;
}
public void setPk(long pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}


@Column( name = "Instant")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getInstant() {
    return instant;
}
public void setInstant(Date instant) {
    this.instant = instant;
}

@Column( name = "Ucid")
public String getUcid() {
    return ucid;
}
public void setUcid(String ucid) {
    this.ucid = ucid;
}

@Column( name = "Routing_Vdn")
public String getRoutingVdn() {
    return routingVdn;
}
public void setRoutingVdn(String routingVdn) {
    this.routingVdn = routingVdn;
}

@Column( name = "Original_Cli")
public String getOriginalCli() {
    return originalCli;
}
public void setOriginalCli(String originalCli) {
    this.originalCli = originalCli;
}

@Column( name = "Original_Dnis")
public String getOriginalDnis() {
    return originalDnis;
}
public void setOriginalDnis(String originalDnis) {
    this.originalDnis = originalDnis;
}

@Column( name = "Terminating_Station")
public String getTerminatingStation() {
    return terminatingStation;
}
public void setTerminatingStation(String terminatingStation) {
    this.terminatingStation = terminatingStation;
}

@Column( name = "Terminating_Agent")
public String getTerminatingAgent() {
    return terminatingAgent;
}
public void setTerminatingAgent(String terminatingAgent) {
    this.terminatingAgent = terminatingAgent;
}
@Column(name = "Phase_1_Instant")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getPhase1Instant() {
    return phase1Instant;
}
public void setPhase1Instant(Date phase1Instant) {
    this.phase1Instant = phase1Instant;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_1_Internal_Result_Code")
public Integer getPhase1InternalResultCode() {
    return phase1InternalResultCode;
}
public void setPhase1InternalResultCode(Integer phase1InternalResultCode) {
    this.phase1InternalResultCode = phase1InternalResultCode;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_1_External_Result_Code")
public Integer getPhase1ExternalResultCode() {
    return phase1ExternalResultCode;
}
public void setPhase1ExternalResultCode(int phase1ExternalResultCode) {
    this.phase1ExternalResultCode = phase1ExternalResultCode;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_1_Message")
public String getPhase1Message() {
    return phase1Message;
}
public void setPhase1Message(String phase1Message) {
    this.phase1Message = phase1Message;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_2_Instant")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getPhase2Instant() {
    return phase2Instant;
}
public void setPhase2Instant(Date phase2Instant) {
    this.phase2Instant = phase2Instant;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_2_Internal_Result_Code")
public Integer getPhase2InternalResultCode() {
    return phase2InternalResultCode;
}
public void setPhase2InternalResultCode(Integer phase2InternalResultCode) {
    this.phase2InternalResultCode = phase2InternalResultCode;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_2_External_Result_Code")
public Integer getPhase2ExternalResultCode() {
    return phase2ExternalResultCode;
}
public void setPhase2ExternalResultCode(Integer phase2ExternalResultCode) {
    this.phase2ExternalResultCode = phase2ExternalResultCode;
}

@Column(name = "Phase_2_Message")
public String getPhase2Message() {
    return phase2Message;
}
public void setPhase2Message(String phase2Message) {
    this.phase2Message = phase2Message;
}

@Column(name = "Server")
public String getServer() {
    return server;
}
public void setServer(String server) {
    this.server = server;
}   
}
```

The exception occurs on the setter for "phase1InternalResultCode" which is null in the DB.

I'm running this in JBoss 5.1.0 and using Hibernate 3.6.0 Final

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I've managed to get this working by putting the annotations on the variables rather than the getters.

This appears to work fine, although I'm aware it's not best practice.